# Detect new values after firing an action then pass them an attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The application renders a table of an array of values in table rows, the mission is to detect the new table rows that are rendered after doing an action 'REFRESH' the table and pass them a new class name for the new rows.

As a new to react and redux , I can do it right , There are many methods I know.

- We can create an array called oldResult = []
- pass the old rows to it
- loop over oldResult[] to detect the new values

here's the function :

```
let oldOrders = []
    const getNewOrders = (orders) => {
        oldOrders.push(OrderList.orders);
        for (let i in orders){
            if (orders.i != oldOrders[i]){
                return this.order.state = 'newClickablerow'
            }
        }
    }
```

here's rendering of the table rows:

```
<tr key={i.toString()}
                onClick={_onClick}
                className={'clickableRow'}
                onMouseLeave={() => this.props.selectOrder(null)}
                onMouseEnter={() => this.props.selectOrder(order)}>
                <td data-label='Bewertung'>
                    {this._renderScore(score, order.creation_date)}
                </td>
                <td data-label='Börse'>
                    <img src={TranseuLogo} className="ordertable-logo"/>
                </td>
                <td data-label='Von'>
                    {renderLocation(order.pickup.location)}
                </td>
                <td data-label='Nach'>
                    {renderLocation(order.delivery.location)}
                </td>
                <td data-label='Vor-/Haupt-/Nachlauf'>
                    {renderRoute(deadhead, order.route, bobtail)}
                </td>
                <td data-label='Fracht'>
                    <CargoSummary
                        content={{bodytypes: this.props.content.bodytypes}}
                        cargo={order.cargo}/>
                </td>
            </tr>)
```

and this is the reducer which pass the values to the table :

```
function orders(state = [], action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_ORDERS:
        return action.orders;
    case RECEIVE_ORDERS_ERROR:
        return []
    case REFRESH:    
    default:
        return state;
}
```

}

I dont know how to fire the function and use it when the REFRESH action is fired , what should i do in case of refresh?

and how to change the state (class name of the table row) ?
I searched and found that I can do that by changing the row state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        className : 'clickablerow'
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you defining as a new row? When a new row is added then all other rows are considered old? This will result in only 1 new row each time

Comment: new row data , I mean there is 10 table rows holds some data , when refreshing the rows layout still the same but some row's data maybe updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid redux state mutation to prevent bugs. Check out the Redux documentation for explanation and code examples: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays

Depending on your exact use case (like update / add / remove items) you could map over and compare every item using the array index, and add a boolean property like "isNew" on the order object. If you want to also check for updated items and if items can be removed then it would be better to use an object with unique IDs as the key to loop over every item.

You don't need to use local "state" on the order if you just want to render the className when updated from redux state, unless you also want to change it afterwards (like clicking it or removing the className again after a few seconds).

If you want to compare the whole object properties you could use utility methods like `lodash.isEqual` and `lodash.omit` to remove the "isNew" property before comparing to the new value, otherwise if you just want to add/remove items you can only compare the ID for example...

Didn't test this code but with using arrays of order objects and just checking if the object at the same position has the same ID to add "isNew" boolean value it would look something like this:

```
function orders(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_ORDERS:
        return action.orders;
    case RECEIVE_ORDERS_ERROR:
        return []
    case REFRESH:
        return refreshOrders(state.orders, action.orders)
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

function refreshOrders (oldOrders, newOrders) {
  return newOrders.map((newOrder, i) => {
    // compare ID for same index and add a property isNew if it's different
    const oldOrder = oldOrders[i] || {} // default to empty object if not found
    const isNew = oldOrder.id === newOrder.id
    return { ...newOrder, isNew }
  })
}
```

Updated and simplified my answer, since I don't fully understand your requirements based on the explanation, so if this is enough to understand please mark this as answer or further explain what exactly you need to do (if you need to add / remove and also update items and if this class will only change after refreshing etc.)

Comment: Thanks robin your answer had covered alot of things that helped me to finish this task